# How to convert between String and JsonNode use toString() method and JsonNode(String) constructor

Tags: java, unirest

I just need some guidance in writing this so that I understand the concept:

Basically I need to convert between a String and a JsonNode and I have seen an answer which states what to do, but as a novice developer, I am unsure what it means. If I can see it implemented then it will help.

Below is my json node for a response:

```
    public void hitEndpoint(String endpoint) {
                DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFactory.getScenarioDataStore();
                HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse;
                String url = "xxx/xxx";
                try {
                    httpResponse = Unirest.post(url)
                            .asJson();
                    dataStore.put("httpResponse", httpResponse);
        ...

}
```

Below I am trying to cast the value so I can retrieve a value from the json:

```
public void RetrieveExampleNode(String endpoint){
    DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFactory.getScenarioDataStore();
    JsonNode httpResponse = (JsonNode) dataStore.get("httpResponse");
    String getExampleNode = httpResponse.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("test").getJSONObject(0).get("example").toString();
   //issue above is that it doesn't recognise getBody. When I remove getBody() and run the code, it still gives me a class cast exception error in the line where states JsonNode httpResponse = ...
}
```

JSON trying to parse and currently retrieved by httpResponse in the above code:

```
{"test": [{"example": "2019-09-18T04:32:12Z"}, {"type": "application/json","other": {"name": Test Tester}}]}
```

I'm using uniRest 1.4.9

Comment: so is your question specific to the how-to convert String to JSON Node and vice visa ot the issue is with unirest dataStore response?

Comment: @Hades specific to the how-to convert String to JSON Node and vice visa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example is converting JSON string to JSONObject

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

   String jsonString  = "{\"test\": [{\"example\": \"2019-09-18T04:32:12Z\"}, {\"type\": \"application/json\",\"other\": {\"name\": Test Tester}}]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Edited answer

```
//For Get using Unirest
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse = Unirest.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").asJson();
        String responseString = httpResponse.getBody().toString();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseString); //Converting to JSONObject since it supports more functionalities
        System.out.println(object.keySet());


        //For Post using Unirest
        httpResponse = Unirest.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").body("This is sample Body").asJson();
        object = new JSONObject(responseString);
        System.out.println(object.keySet());
```

Comment: Hi Hades, efore your answer I have been trying with JsonObject but with no luck. I think my problem is how to get hhtpresponse from the get datastore and then from there get the json node as a string. Can you use my example to show me your thought on tackling this?

Comment: @BruceyBandit I have added some example of Get and Post using uniRest please see if it helps you.